# Is time comlexity O((log(N))^2) equivalent to O(sqrt(N))?

Tags: math, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I saw the following equivalence in the [lowest common ancestor problem](https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/lca_farachcoltonbender.html):
[image: 1]
but I don't understand why, so I want to figure out how to prove:
[image]

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is not about programming, but about maths or theoretical computer science

Comment: But anyway, from the well known inequality `log x < x - 1`, by setting x = fourth root of N, you get `(log N) < 4*(fourth root of N) - 4` which proves log N is in O(fourth root of N). By squaring, you prove that (log N)^2 is in O(square root of N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by @Joni, you can prove that `log(N)^2 < 16 * sqrt(N)`, which gives the expected big-O notation.

But you might be troubled because this equal sign is a ["one way" one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Equals_sign):

`O(log(N)^2) = O(sqrt(N))` is true, but
`O(sqrt(N)) = O(log(N)^2)` is false!